# What would be the best optimization strategy for when the cost function is the sum of a Boolean condition?

Tags: python, optimization

There is a dataset with two columns X_i_0 and X_i_1, where i is ith data point. T_0 and T_1 and variables which I would like to optimize.

I would like to minimize the following equation:

```
    MIN COST = SUM( (X_i_0>T_0 or X_i_1>T_1) and X_i_0<T_1)-50
    S.T. COST>=0
```

How can I optimize T_0 and T_1 so that the budget is as close to 50 as possible? I know that linear programming doesn't support  "<" and ">" operators. Are there alternative methods?